# REST API Sobject GetUpdated/GetDeleted on sobjects returns The requested resource does not exist

Tags: rest-api, sobject, error, document

I am trying to use the following -

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_getupdated.htm

On 'Document'.

Authentication and everything is successful, even calls to 'describe' are successful but

`'updated/deleted' return NOT_FOUND.`

What am I missing here .. this is the URL

```
https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Document/updated/​​​?start=2013-05-06T00:00:00+00:00&end=2013-12-31T00:00:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the examples could use a little work.  I was able to get it to work by url encoding the start and end date.  Also saw got the `NOT_FOUND` error but by the end of things couldn't tell you how.

### Request

```
/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Document/updated/?start=2013-12-01T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&end=2013-12-13T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00
```

### Response

{
  "latestDateCovered" : "2013-12-13T00:00:00.000+0000",
  "ids" : [ "015123456789iLOAAY" ]
}

Comment: Yes, it's quite weird. Thanks for the response.
My actual use case is to be notified of any new documents uploaded to the account - { I could potentially use the StreamingApi but my entire infrastructure is based on REST, while the StreamingApi uses Bayeux protocol} - do you think 'updated/deleted' are the best choices for the same. I saw that Box has something called Long Polling - [link](http://developers.box.com/using-long-polling-to-monitor-events/[link] .. is there a REST equivalent of the same in Salesforce ? Many thanks for the response.

Comment: That's a really good question, could you repost as a separate question?  As a general rule a QA site is a lot better if each discussion focuses narrowly on the original question.

Comment: I just filed a doc bug on this - thanks for posting!

Comment: @metadaddy - also, the documentation says we need to pass in the date time in UTC zone ... when I do pass in something like this `start=2013-12-18T07:25:10+0000` - it returns parsing exception.
If however, i send `start=2013-12-18T07:25:10-0800` - it works.

Comment: Are you sure you're urlencoding the '+'? What exactly are you passing when it returns the parsing exception?

Comment: @metadaddy do doc bugs ever get looked at?  I've posted typos so many times and they never seem to get fixed (i.e. I run into the same typo years later) :(

Comment: @Ralph They do; I don't know the process in detail, but I'm guessing there's some triage involved. I've certainly seen doc issues fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the trailing slash before the question mark!

Once I removed that, it worked.

Example:
/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Document/updated?start=2013-12-01T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&end=2013-12-13T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00